# Web applications with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Now I program all my web apps with Flask or Django. (blogs, social networks...). I need templates, db access, controllers, routing...

Now I want to do same web applications, but with javascript.

People tell me : You need NodeJs for server-side, Angular for the front, and for example firebase or mongodb. Or also you can use Express JS.

But can I just use Angular JS and Firebase for start a big web app ? Need I Node if Angular can Access/Update/Delete in my db ?

Answer (score 2):

Angular is a client-side framework, so you'll have to at least have some web server to serve your static files. Other than that, if you're using Firebase, you wouldn't technically need any server-side code to handle your logic - but naturally, that depends strongly on what data your application deals with.

If what Firebase provides, doesn't cut it for your cases though, you will need a server-side, and pretty much any web application framework would do. Node.js (using Express), PHP, ASP.NET, whatever your heart desires.

And yes, Angular works perfectly well for creating big complex web applications.